# How to have an image move up over time (instead of instantly) when using hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have an image rise when you hover over the image. When it rises, I don't want it to rise instantly, I want it to rise over time. I've figured out how to make the opacity decrease over time, but not how to have it rise over time. I'm new to programming and I'm having trouble figuring it out. Let me know if you guys have any ideas or need any more information. Thanks

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
  

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
}

.column img:hover {
  background-color:black;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -5px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a point of reference for the animation to begin in your `.column img` CSS definition.

```
.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;

  /* You need to define where the animation starts */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;

  /* Add this if you want the animation to also happen on un-hover */
  transition-duration: .6s;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/twhitcomb/auynx0m7/10/